Eigenvalues of N×N correlation matrices as N tends to infinity
I want to find a × positive definite correlation matrix, which ensures that as  goes to infinity, only a finite number of eigenvalues remain non-zero, while the rest eigenvalues approach zero.
There is an simple example
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1-\frac{1}{2N} & \cdots & 1-\frac{1}{2N} \\ 1-\frac{1}{2N} & 1 & \cdots & 1-\frac{1}{2N} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 1-\frac{1}{2N} & 1-\frac{1}{2N} & \cdots & 1  \end{pmatrix}
Its eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=1-(N-1)(\frac{1}{2N}-1)$, $\lambda_2=...\lambda_N=\frac{1}{2N}$. As $N$ goes to infinity, only $\lambda_1$ remains non-zero.
But this example is too simple. I want to find a matrix such that, as N tends to infinity, it has two or three eigenvalues that do not tend to zero. If it's difficult to construct such an example, can you conclude whether such a matrix necessarily exists? And why?

just take the direct sum $B=A\oplus A\oplus A\cdots$ of several copies of your matrix $A$, and then mix the elements $OBO^\top$ by conjugating with an orthogonal matrix $O$.

@CarloBeenakker Thank you a lot! I have another confusion. How to ensure that the orthogonal similarity transformation $OBO^\top$ is a correlation matrix?

every symmetric positive semi-definite matrix is a covariance matrix, which you can then convert into a correlation matrix as explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix

@CarloBeenakker However, the eigenvalues change when we convert the covariance matrix into a correlation matrix. How to ensure that the eigenvalues of the latter satisfy the requirement of the problem?
